# Could not find iPhone 6 simulator after upgrade to Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, react-native

I updated to Xcode 10 and since I did that, I can't run the simulator in terminal with the command `react-native run-ios`. I get this error:

> Could not find iPhone 6 simulator

When I go to Xcode > Window > Devices and Simulator the simulator is there and when I do `xcrun simctl list devices` I also see the list of simulator.

I can run the app on my phone with `react-native run-ios --device` and from Xcode, and I tried with multiple apps so it's not the app.

When I go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations, Xcode 10.0 (10A255) is selected at Command Line Tools.

I tried restarting the computer, as well as deleting and re-installing Xcode.

Any ideas what it could be?

Here is my setup:

- MacOs High Sierra 10.13.6
- Xcode Version 10.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.57.1

Comment: Maybe it's searching for a simulator with different iOS version? Same error happens to me when trying to initialize from command line.

Comment: In my case it opens an iPhone 6 iOS 8.1 simulator but then shows an error message just like yours. (`Could not find iPhone 6 simulator`)

Comment: @JoseVf: On my side, it's not opening anything.
I also tried : 
-removing all simulator (in Xcode > Window > Devices and Simulator ) except iPhone 6 and running `react-native run-ios` again
-adding a new simulator with a new name<br/>
-trying to open the simulator with `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"`

Nothing works :(

Comment: @JoseVf: Did this happened to you after upgrading to Xcode 10 as well? Are you on MacOs High Sierra 10.13.6 ?

Comment: Xcode 10 and macOS Mojave (10.14), but also happened on High Sierra

Answer (score 22):

I went to node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

And i've replaced:

`if (version.indexOf('iOS') !== 0 )`

with

`if (!version.includes("iOS" ))`

And

`if (simulator.availability !== '(available)')`

with

`if (simulator.isAvailable !== true)`

Comment: Worked for me in RN 0.55.4 - I cant believe a company like Facebook release such bug.

Comment: @chenop I have the same version like U and it doesn't work for me

Comment: Actually i upgraded to Version 60 
And this issue is gone

Answer (score 18):

I had similar issue.
React Native - 0.52.3, XCode - 10.2 beta 2

```
function findMatchingSimulator(simulators, simulatorName) {
  if (!simulators.devices) {
    return null;
  }
  const devices = simulators.devices;
  var match;
  for (let version in devices) {
    // Making sure the version of the simulator is an iOS (Removes Apple Watch, etc)
    if (!version.includes('iOS')) {
      continue;
    }
    [...]
  }
}
```

- Open file: `node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`
- Check if your device version is correct, e.g: in line 29 `console.log(version)`
- Compare it with condition in line 30: `if (version.indexOf('iOS') !== 0) {`

I had versions list like this:

```
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-5-0 -1
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-12-1 -1
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-12-2 -1
```

Any of my versions doesn't return true in this condition... If you have it

- Replace `version.indexOf('iOS') !== 0` with `!version.includes('iOS')` and it solve this issue for me.

Comment: Wow. That fixed it for me. I changed `version.start('iOS')` to `version.includes('iOS')` and that fixed it. It amazes me what gets past QA at Facebook's React Native team.

Comment: This was my issue as well

Comment: Works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The bug has been fixed in `react-native` so you can update the package in the package.json:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u react-native
npm install
```

Comment: @chenop it should solve the issue of the missing iOS simulator, however, upgrading  react-native might cause problems within your app as you'll need to migrate.

Comment: Telling someone to upgrade react-native is terribly naive advice that you hand-wave away with "might cause problems"

Comment: @MikeWalston Yes, admittedly, it's a very naive solution. "Might cause problems" was poor wording on my part. With any upgrade to core software within a project you'll need to weigh any backwards compatibility issues with the benefit of the bug fix which, in this case, is better logic for locating the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 8):

Found something that resolved my problem.
You need to go in `local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js` in react-native node module and change line 37 for

```
if (
        simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
        simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'
) {`
```

More info on the solution and the problem on react-native github :
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/1031872
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21571

Comment: For a better quality response not just paste the link, explain a little what to do and then paste the link. This response will get obsolete if the link broke.

Comment: @JoseVf: Updated ;)

Comment: This is `<your-react-native-project>/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js` for anyone that was unsure or the exact location.

Comment: This should now be `simulator.isAvailable !== true`

Answer (score 5):

I just want to share with you guys how I fixed it, maybe it can help someone.

**Edit this file:** node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

Change:

```
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
  continue;
}
```

To:

```
if (!version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS') 
    && !version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS')) {
  continue;
}
```

It worked for me.

I used **console.log(version)** to see what I got from the variable **version** and the value wasn't expected as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

it can be solved to fix the file below.

```
/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js
```

replace this line

```
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
```

with

```
if (!version.includes('iOS') && !version.includes('tvOS')) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Using react-native version `0.55.3` with **XCode 10** I had to do **two** changes to get `react-native run-ios` running.

Inside `node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`:

1. The change as described by @martin-leroux :

   Change

   ```
   // Skipping non-available simulator
   if (simulator.availability !== true) {
   ```

   to

   ```
   // Skipping non-available simulator
   if (
       simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
       simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'
   ) {`
   ```
2. Change the line mentioned by @samernady :

   Change

   ```
   // Making sure the version of the simulator is an iOS or tvOS (Removes Apple Watch, etc)
   if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
   ```

   to

   ```
   // Making sure the version of the simulator is an iOS or tvOS (Removes Apple Watch, etc)
   if (!version.includes('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I have a self-refactored version of findMatchingSimulator.js. If someone in the future still facing this issue and the solutions mentioned above couldn't solve your problem, just overwrite the findMatchingSimulator-Method in ...node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js
with following code:

```
   function findMatchingSimulator(simulators, simulatorName) {
      if (!simulators.devices) {
        return null;
      }
      const devices = simulators.devices;
      var match = null;
      for(let version in devices){
          //Skip WatchOS
          if(!version.includes("tvOS") && !version.includes("iOS")){
              continue;
          }

          for(let d in devices[version]){
              var currentDevice = devices[version][d];
              if(!currentDevice.isAvailable){
                  continue;
              }
              if(currentDevice.state === "Booted" ){
                  let booted = currentDevice.state === "Booted";
                  if(currentDevice.name === simulatorName ){
                      return {
                              udid: currentDevice.udid,
                              name: currentDevice.name,
                              booted,
                              version,
                      };
                  }else if(!match){
                      //keep track of first available & bootable device
                      match = {
                         udid: currentDevice.udid,
                         name: currentDevice.name,
                         booted,
                         version,
                      };
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      if (match) {
        return match;
      }
      return null;
    }
   }
```

EDIT: This code will choose an already opened simulator and you're still good to go with the --simulator="NAME" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

one option which worked for me

Check list of simulators installed in your mac using

```
xcrun simctl list --json devices
```

on list of simulator, choose any simulator name and run like this

```
react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone 6s'
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Go to node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/ and in findMatchingSimulator.js replace line 30 with

```
if (version.indexOf('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS') !== 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xcrun simctl list --json devices
```

Edit `node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js` yourself.
Ensure that the `findMatchingSimulator` function returns an `match` object like

```
{
    udid: simulator.udid,
    name: simulator.name,
    version
}
```

Answer (score -1):

remove these lines from package.json
 "react": "XXXXXXXX",
 "react-native": "YYYYYYYYY",

then run
npm install --save react-native react